# Record screen iPhone during setup assistant

Tags: ios, screen-capture, quicktime

Using the screen recording method of connecting my iOS device directly to a MacOS system and recording through quicktime - is it possible to record the setup assistant? Or is recording only capable once the phone is set up and booted into iOS.

Comment: Worked through it a bit more and found the issue. I was choosing new screen recording and the iPhone wasn't available in the list (it was available as a mic but not video source). i tried again with movie recording and everything worked perfectly,

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's possible. After launching quicktime, choose File > New Movie Recording (I was thrown off at first because I kept choosing New Screen Recording).

Once I correctly chose new movie recording, I was able to capture right from the initial setup screen (where it's scrolling through 'hello' in different languages).